# Getting log information from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My application uses PostgreSQL for storing data. I need to gather information about all user actions (any INSERTs, UPDATEs or DELETEs) executed on the database. This made me wonder whether PostgreSQL provides any default implementations/tables for this? As per my prior searches, I haven't found anything usable yet - however proper confirmation to my suspicions would be nice. If PostgreSQL truly doesn't provide any default implementations for this, then I will design my own history table.

Comment: Something that might also be of help here is PostgreSQL's [Audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports several methods for logging server messages, including `stderr`, `csvlog` and `syslog`. On Windows, `eventlog` is also supported. Set this parameter to a list of desired log destinations separated by commas. The default is to log to `stderr` only. This parameter can only be set in the `postgresql.conf` file or on the server command line.

[**SEE HERE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html)

Comment: The Q mentions "history table". I doubt an unstructured textual logfile will help here.